# What is the most secure/reliable CSPRNG currently available?

Tags: random-number-generator, randomness, pseudo-random-generator, pseudo-random-function

In terms of period length, uniformity/distribution, what is the most secure/reliable CSPRNG currently available?

Comment: Try the Yarrow suite of Algorithms by Bruce Schneier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most secure CSPRNG would be one which produces a stream indistinguishable from random data without knowledge of the key, and which takes a key large enough that an exhaustive search of the key space is impossible. It turns out that there are *many* such CSPRNGs:

- ChaCha and Salsa20 are 256-bit stream ciphers which can output $2^{64} \times 512$ bits of data per key.<sup>*</sup> After this, the output immediately wraps back to the beginning, so re-key before this.
- AES in CTR mode is secure, but becomes distinguishable after generating about $2^{64} \times 128$ bits. The distinguishability slowly goes up over time as more data is produced.
- HMAC_DRBG and Hash_DRBG are NIST standards that use a secure hash function, but are often too slow and are usually only found in applications that must be FIPS-certified.

There are many more which I could list, but not all are popular. ISAAC for example is a (likely) secure CSPRNG with no known weaknesses, but it hasn't been the subject of a large amount of research for this reason. This alone is a reason to avoid it if you need high security.

If you are asking which CSPRNG is *least likely* to be the subject of major cryptanalytic breakthroughs in the future (i.e. which have the highest security margin), then the answer would be large enough to fill entire cryptography journals, which they indeed do. In general, ChaCha20 (ChaCha with 20 rounds) is *currently* thought by many to have one of the highest security margins. But they're all secure.

<sub>* The actual period of the cipher depends on the length of the counter. It is normally 64 bits, but in some implementations, such as TLS, it may be only 32 bits to make room for a larger nonce (32:96 vs 64:64). The counter size is fairly arbitrary.</sub>